# call dlopen from gdb

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, dlopen

I want to load shared library (.so) from gdb, I found this command :

```
(gdb) call dlopen("path/to/lib.so",..)
```

But it doesn't work, I link my program with -ldl.

The error I get is:

```
No symbol "dlopen" in current context
```

what did I miss ?

Comment: You don't mention how it fails.

Comment: right, I got this : No symbol "dlopen" in current context

Comment: Did you *start* the program? What do `info shared` and `info func dlopen` say?

Comment: of course it's running, for the first command : 0x00007ffff7dd7ac0 0x00007ffff7df5640 Yes * /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 0x00007ffff7a2d8b0 0x00007ffff7b7ff14 Yes * /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6. The second one doesn't display result !!

Answer (score 1):

I found a command that resolve the half of this topic. I explain:
First, you should load the shared object into the process:

```
(gdb) set environment LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/libdl.so
```

After that, we define the file to debbuging

```
(gdb) file pgm
```

For testing, we put breakpoint in main i.e

```
(gdb) break main
```

Now, we run the program

```
(gdb) run
```

and we call dlopen

```
(gdb) call dlopen("/path/to/lib.so",2)
```

until now it's work, but when I put the last command, I have:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de7f09 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function 
(_gdb_expr) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

nothing changes when I modify 'unwindonsignal to (on/off)'

What did I forget this time ?

[useful](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581737)